# API rate limit exceeded for user ID for Github Search APIs

Tags: github, github-api

I have a use case where I have to run the github search APIs repeatedly. However sometimes in between I get the error below:

```
"API rate limit exceeded for user ID XXXXX".
```

How Can I avoid this error? Is there any way?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible but maybe you could try woar arounds: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#rate-limiting

Comment: That's not exactly an *error* (and has nothing to do with Git). It's just GitHub's way of preventing you from executing a denial of service attack. They return an error message, instead of an API result, to get you to slow down. Don't try to get around it: that's just perpetuating your DoS attack. (Consider using Git, instead of using GitHub's API, for things that need a lot of local work.)

Answer (score 5):

Github rest api has following rate limit:

- For **unauthenticated** requests, the rate limit allows for up to **60** requests per hour. Unauthenticated requests are associated with the originating IP address
- For **authenticated** requests(either by OAuth applications or by a personal access token), the rate limit allows for up to **5,000** requests per hour and per authenticated user.